# complex logarithm : why do we have to precise always the branch cut despite to make a convention as $\arcsin$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis, we define the Complex Logarithm by $$\log(z)=\log|z|+i\arg(z).$$

So, I understand that it is not well define as written because $\arg(z)$ is a well defined function only if we restrict it to an open interval of length $2\pi$. So, let restrict it to $(0,2\pi)$. Then $\log(z)$ is a well defined and holomorphic function on $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R^-$.

The thing I don't understand is why do we only have to precise a branch cut to the Complex logarithm, and not say that it's always $(0,2\pi)$ ? I'm asking this question because for example, with $\arcsin$ function (as a real function) we don't precise that we take it in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ or $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ or $(3\pi/2,5\pi/4)$, what would could completely do. So in the case of $\arcsin$ we made this clear definition that is the inverse function of the sinus that is taken in $(-\pi/2,\pi)$. And I was wondering why with the complex logarithme, author always precise either the principle branch cut, or an other interval as $(-\pi,\pi)$ or I saw once the branch cut $(-2\pi,0)$. I guess that if people do that, there is a reason, so can someone explain why do we make a convention as we do with $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ function ?

Comment: The arc sine is rarely dealt with in the complex (though this is possible), contrary to the logarithm. This makes the difference. In a similar way, the main branch of $\sqrt[3]z$ is not always the same in the complex.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thanks for your answer. I added some details : avoid the fact that $\arcsin$ is in $\mathbb C$ but only as a function $[0,1]\to [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Why as a real function we restrict the image of $\arcsin$ to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ by convention, whereas in the complex logarithm we don't put this convention, and we have always to precise the brach cut. In other word, why don't we define the complex logarithm with $\arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi)$ all the time ?

Comment: You just repeat your question. I won't repeat my comment.

Comment: Sorry if you have the impression that I repeat my question, but your comment is not clear for me. I don't see in what the $arcsin$ is rarely dealt with the complex function make the difference... why the fact that dealing with complex number make things completely different ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: First of all, the interval for the principle Arg must be **half-open**.  Second of all, just as there is a commonly used (but perhaps not universally used) convention that the principle Arg is in $(-\pi, \pi]$, there is a similar (but less commonly) used convention that ArcSin is in the **closed** interval $[\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}].$  The 2nd convention is (**arguably**) less common only because a disproportionate number of complex analysis problems involve the principle Arg rather than the principle ArcSin.

Comment: Continuing previous comment, I am self-studying "An Introduction To Complex Function Theory" (Bruce Palka), which includes **both** conventions in its chapter 1.